# How to create numpy array of images

Tags: python, opencv

Just a beginner to python.. 
I'm trying to create array of images.

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

PATH = os.getcwd()
data_path = PATH + '/data1'
data_path_folder = os.listdir(data_path)

X_data = []

for image in data_path:
   img = cv2.imread(data_path + "/" +image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
   img_resize = cv2.resize(img,(128,128))
   X_data.append(img_resize)

img_data = np.array(X_data)
img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
img_data /=255
print(img_data.shape)
```

ERROR
     cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4044: error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function cv::resize

Comment: The error is telling you that your `img` is invalid, either it's duff or it doesn't have a valid size.

Comment: I've tried changing images, but still showing the same error. Can you tell solution for it.

Comment: Your error here is that you're failing to load the image, you need to debug that first

Comment: The result of `os.listdir()` contains  the paths `.`, `..`  A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001890/why-cant-i-access-images/48002038#48002038

Comment: Solved! i was messing with the directory path. But now i'm using glob module. Much easier..Thanks everyone...!

Answer (score 0):

It seems a tiny error....
error msg says there are invalid input for resize.

I think you have to get correct image file name from correct list.

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

PATH = os.getcwd()
data_path = PATH + '/data1'
data_path_folder = os.listdir(data_path)

X_data = []

for image in data_path_folder:  # ADD '_folder'
   img = cv2.imread(data_path + "/" +image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
   img_resize = cv2.resize(img,(128,128))
   X_data.append(img_resize)

img_data = np.array(X_data)
img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
img_data /=255
print(img_data.shape)
```