# How can we read corresponding images from two different folders?

Tags: python

Basically my directory structure is:
/Dir1:
-- image1.png
-- image2.png
.
.
.
/Dir2:
--image1.png
--image2.png
.
.
.
What I have to do is read corresponding images like image1.png or image2.png from Dir1 and Dir2, and then perform some operation like xor or anything other. My problem is with single for loop I am finding it difficult to traverse.
What I am trying:

```
    from os import listdir
    d1 = 'Dir1'
    d2 = 'Dir2'
    d3 = 'Dir3'
    f1 = [f for f in listdir(d1) if isfile(join(d1,f))]
    f2 = [f for f in listdir(d2) if isfile(join(d2,f))]
    for ( what to put here ?? ) in (what to put here?? ):
        img1 = # read image from d1
        img2 = # read image from d2
        # perform some operation
        #save to d3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read images from a directory with Python and OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001890/how-to-read-images-from-a-directory-with-python-and-opencv)

Comment: Is the `zip` method what you're looking for? It will allow you to iterate over two lists at the same time https://stackoverflow.com/a/49783740/6678216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for fn1, fn2 in zip(f1, f2)
```

... could help if only you were sure that corresponding elements of `f1` and `f2` are in the same order **BUT** `listdir` does not guarantee this. Maybe you'll better do a simple `for` loop over filenames in one directory and inside just read the same filename from both, if they exist.

By the way, if content of directories can be different, you can easily get their common filenames this way:

```
f1 = {f for f in listdir(d1) if isfile(join(d1,f))}
f2 = {f for f in listdir(d2) if isfile(join(d2,f))}
f_common = list(f1 & f2)
```